# Intermittently selenium tests are failing with "java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException" error while opening application urll

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, docker-selenium

While running suite on selenium grid 4.8.1, I am intermittently getting below error while opening the url itself.
I am using below configuration:

1. selenium grid version 4.8.1
2. chrome version 110
3. Running on docker selenium grid setup on RHEL liniux machine.

.

```
java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException: request timed out Build info: version: '4.8.1', revision: '8ebccac989' System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '<OS_VERSION>', java.version: '11.0.2' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Command: [0a902ee7ac88388d017f325cefd6e0d7, get {url=<APP_URL>}] Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 110.0.5481.77, chrome: {chromedriverVersion:
110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8e..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.D8sHzb}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:44241}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:bidiEnabled: false, se:cdp: ws://<IP_ADDRESS>:4444/sessi..., se:cdpVersion: 110.0.5481.77, se:vnc: ws://<IP_ADDRESS>:4444/sessi..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://<IP_ADDRESS>:7900, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true} Session ID: 0a902ee7ac88388d017f325cefd6e0d7
```

I tried retrying the get call for URL but even then it is fialing with same error post loading the url.